# In Django, Why does my database manager fail?

Tags: python, django

I am learning managers for the first time.
I am trying to figure out how to set these managers correctly.  It appears that managers are similar in philosophy as a SQL View.

Here is my manager and class:

```
class SubscriptionManager(models.Manager):

    def active_officers(self):
        officers = self.get_queryset().filter(Modified__gte=datetime.now()-timedelta(days=365)).filter(Subscription_Type='O')
        return officers

    def lifer(self):
        return self.get_queryset().filter(Lifetime=True)

class Subscription(models.Model):
    SType = (
        ('C', 'Civilian'),
        ('E', 'Enlisted'),
        ('O', 'Officer'),
    )
    Subscription_Type = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=SType)
    Lifetime = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    Member = models.ForeignKey(Member)
    Modified = models.DateField()

    objects = SubscriptionManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.Member.first_name + " " + self.Member.last_name + ": " + self.Subscription_Type + "; last modified: " + self.Modified.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
```

Once set I can still execute `Subscription.objects.all()` with no problems, bu if I fire off `Subscription.objects.lifer()`, I receive the following error: `AttributeError: 'Manager' object has no attribute 'lifer'`

I'm in python 3.4.  What am I missing?
Thanks

Comment: Hmm this should have worked and I just copy and pasted it and it works for me

Answer (score 0):

Your code that you pasted above is correct and it works for me after copy and pasting.

Somewhere else in your code you have it listed as an attribute I believe `Subscription.objects.lifer` instead of the method `Subscription.objects.lifer()` Give that a search and I believe that should clear your error.

Comment: where would I look as an attribute?  I finished the class and attempted to execute the command.  I don't know where to look.

Comment: I figured it out.  I'm using pycharm, and I the python console didn't have the functions imported correctly.  I restarted the console, and they fired right up.